# How to fix the footer at the end of the screen

Tags: html, css

I want the footer is fixed at the end of the screen
I added to the `<h:body style="display: block;">` there is no change ,i added to `<div id="footer">` the attribute `style="position: fixed"` and there is no change.
the picture of the footer of my page is below
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this html code which will work. **BUT** it takes `#footer` **out of the document flow**. So that's why you will have to use `width: 100%`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *
        {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        html, body
        {
            min-height: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #footer
        {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
           /* width: 100%; */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="footer">
        this is a footer
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So instead I would propose to use this html structure - which **will remain document flow** and provide you with a clean (html4) structure.

```
<style type="text/css">
    *
    {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    html, body
    {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #header  { height: 20%;  }
    #content { height: 70%;  }
    #footer  { height: 10%;  }
</style>

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer">
    this is a footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this code :

```
`#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}`
```

This should work fairly well in all browsers. Tell me if you have any further problems with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS rules:

```
#footer {
  // Specify the fixed position for the footer
  position: fixed;

  // Position it at the bottom of the screen
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;

  // Make it span across 100% of the browser's width
  width:100%;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

HTML : 
    
      
        #conteneur {
          height : 100%;
        }
      </style>

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    Body
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS :

```
html, body {
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
  height : 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  position : relative; 
  min-height : 100%;
  background : green;
}

#container {
  padding-bottom : 6em; /* padding-bottom = footer height */
}

#footer {
  position : absolute;
  width : 100%; 
  height : 6em;
  bottom : 0; /* set footer at bottom */
  left : 0; /* set footer at left */
  background : red;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkwpA/)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem for you, you can check it at Fiddle

```
<body>  

<div id="content">  

 <div id="text"></div>  

</div>  

<div id="footer"></div>  

</body> 


* {  
 margin: 0;  
 padding: 0;  
}  
html, body {height: 100%;} 

#content {  
 position: relative;  
 min-height: 100%;
 border:1px solid red;
}  

* html #content {  
 height: 100%;

}  
#text {  
 padding-bottom: 100px;
        border:1px solid green;
}  
#footer {  
 position: relative;  
 height: 80px;  
 margin-top: -80px; 
 border:2px solid black;
}
```

see Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Znbx/